# Parsing XML unbound prefix : error

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to parse the input but I keep getting and unbound prefix : error.

I know this error is something to do with 'data:bbox' tag and changing it to just 'data' solves the problem. But I have so many documents that use the same tag 'data:bbox'.

Is there a way around?

The code I am using is:

```
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    input = '''<data>
    <sourcefile filename ="file:/C:/temp/S1-T1-C/S1-T1-C/video/pets2006/S1-T1-C/3/3.info">

    <object framespan="244:309" id="0" name="Bag objects">
        <attribute name="bagBoundingBox">
            <data:bbox framespan="244:244" height="51" width="47" x="3" y="428"/>
        </attribute>
    </object>

    <object framespan="441:484" id="1" name="Bag objects">
        <attribute name="bagBoundingBox">
            <data:bbox framespan="259:259" height="54" width="72" x="67" y="450"/>
        </attribute>
    </object>

   </sourcefile>
</data>'''

data = ET.fromstring(input)
lst = data.findall('sourcefile/object')
print ('Object count:', len(lst))

for object in lst:
     print ("*****Object*****" + '\n')
     print ('Object ID', object.get("id"))
     print ('Frame numbers:', object.get("framespan"))

boundingBoxes = object.findall('attribute/data')
for boundingBox in boundingBoxes:
    print ("--------Bounding Box --------")     
    print ('Bounding box frame number: ', boundingBox.get("framespan"))
    print ('Height of bounding box: ', boundingBox.get("height"))
    print ('Width of bounding box: ', boundingBox.get("width"))
    print ('X coordinate of bounding box: ', boundingBox.get("x"))
    print ('Y coordinate of bounding box: ', boundingBox.get("y"))
```

Comment: The error is probably because `bbox` is prefixed with the `data` namespace, but that namespace is nowhere defined. In that sense, the XML is invalid. Presumably, somewhere the namespace `data` should be defined in those documents, but may have gotten lost? If those documents are online in normal format, a tool like `sed` can fix this very easily and quickly for you (I'd change it to just `bbox` though`, instead of `data`. `bbox` is the actual name, but when `data:` is removed, it's simply put in the global namespace).

Comment: Yeah that is what I did. I changed all the `data:bbox` to just `bbox`. Thank you for your reply.